# How to share text and images to the instagram in react, or native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, instagram

I am creating nocode application in adalo constructor. There are posts with images and description in my project. I want to make sharing options to instagram and facebook. There are two ways, how can I integrate with something: by sending simple HTTP call, or by creating custom component in react, or react native. I saw that [react-native-share](https://react-native-share.github.io/react-native-share/docs/install/) library, but it doesn't want to run in adalo, maybe there is simple decision how can I make this without any libraries, or maybe there are another libraries which can run in adalo?